# Python 3.4/Ftputil 3.4 only runs a single command then exits

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, ftp, ftputil

I'm currently making the base of a personal ftp program, using ftputil 3.4 and python 3.4, ive successfully gotten it to log in and i can run follow up commands in the python interpreter but after a single command it goes back to the main interpreter. as an example if i login, then run list, then it lists once, if i were to try it again it returns the result of typing list in pythons idle shell.

```
import ftputil

User = input()
Password = input()
ftp = ftputil.FTPHost('ip', User, Password)

names = ftp.listdir(ftp.curdir)
print(names)

userinput = input()
if userinput == 'list':
print(names)

#not yet implemented download function
#if userinput == 'get': 
#   ftp.
```

I'm looking for a way to keep the program from 'closing' so that i can continue running commands to and from the ftp server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell python you want to repeat the section of the code. In this case, a while loop probably would do the trick.

```
import ftputil
# ...
while True:
    userinput = input()
    # ...
```

This is an infinite loop, so to kill it you'll probably have to press `Ctrl+C`. Alternatively, if you want to implement an exit command you could do so by doing something like the following;

```
while userinput != "exit":
```

Comment: Just asking to expand my own knowledge, the != means while not exit correct?

Comment: While `userinput` does not equal the string `"exit"`, continue to repeat.

Comment: where would you place that in the code i have, i placed it like so
   ` userinput = input()`
   ` while userinput != "exit":`
   ` if userinput == 'list':`
`        print(names)`

and it infinitly loops the list output

Comment: As I showed in my answer, the while loop should start just **before** requesting user input (and remember to indent everything you wish to repeat)

Comment: i tried a couple times to use the code block, both by spaces and in comments help it says use ``'s to no avail.

i ended up placing it After userinput () because it would say user input wasn't defined when placed before it

Comment: So define it before the loop as well. A simple `userinput = ""` would do the trick.

Comment: I thank you for the help and im proud to have figured that out just before i read your comment. success is rare but oh so sweet